# Comparing two ranges in excel files for differences in formulas rather then values

Tags: vba

It may sound embarrassingly easy but what kind of tweak to the following code should I make to compare formulas rather then values.

```
Sub AutoFill()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    For i = 1 To 10
        For j = 1 To 10

            If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, j) <> ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(i, j) Then
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(i, j).Font.Color = RGB(500, 0, 0)
            Else
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(i, j).Font.Color = RGB(0, 500, 0)
            End If         

        Next j
    Next i 

End Sub
```

Comment: just a FYI Spreadsheet Compare 2013 https://support.office.com/en-us/article/what-you-can-do-with-spreadsheet-inquire-ebaf3d62-2af5-4cb1-af7d-e958cc5fad42

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use `Formula` property of `Range` object

```
Sub AutoFill()
    Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

    For i = 1 To 10
        For j = 1 To 10
            If ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(i, j).Formula <> ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(i, j).Formula Then
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(i, j).Font.Color = RGB(500, 0, 0)
            Else
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Cells(i, j).Font.Color = RGB(0, 500, 0)
            End If
        Next j
    Next i
End Sub
```

or, with a little optimization:

```
Sub AutoFill()
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Range("A1:J10")
        If cell.Formula <> ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range(cell.Address).Formula Then
            cell.Font.Color = RGB(500, 0, 0)
        Else
            cell.Font.Color = RGB(0, 500, 0)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```